# Select rows from DB in dependence of field value in child table

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I want to select some rows from table in dependence of some values from another table. I has this code :

```
$row = Yii::app()->cre->createCommand()
    ->from('test')
    ->queryAll();
```

What where() clause I should write to this?
Explanation:
I has table `test`, and related `test2` where I has `test_id` field and `compare_id` field. I need to get all rows from `test` where `compare_id = 1`

Comment: try to join the other table: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#join()-detail

Comment: this will work if tables not related trought foreign keys?

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare in the where? Can you please add an example?

Comment: I added explanation)

Comment: Is `test_id` a foreign key, that points on the id from the table `test`?

Comment: no. there is no foreign keys in db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work with a join:

```
$row = Yii::app()->cre->createCommand()
    ->from('test')
    ->join('test2','test2.compare_id = test.test_id')
    ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try alternative way like that...

```
$query = "SELECT t1.* FROM test AS t1 JOIN test2 AS t2 ON
          t1.test_id = t2.compare_id 
          WHERE t2.compare_id = $compareId";  

$row = Yii::app()->cre->createCommand($query)->queryAll();  //or Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query)->queryAll();
```